# Entity Framework: Setting correct connection string to SQL Server Compact in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce, embedded-database

I want to use and embedded SQL Server Compact edition in my asp.net mvc 4 project. I try to approaches but I have problems with any approach:

**First attempt**

I have created a new data connection from visual studio and from server explorer of type Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 and I store the `.sdf` file in my asp.net mvc 4 project under `\App_Data` folder (I add this `.sdf` file to this folder). I guess doing this I create and embedded SQL Server Compact database for my web application, am I right?

Finally, I create the following connection string in `web.config`:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\MyDatabaseSQLCe.sdf" />
```

I start my web application but an error occurs, database seems to be not found, well the error says something like:

> SQL Server Compact is not intended for asp.net development

I am not sure if the connection string above described is the correct.

**Second attempt**

Also I have downloaded the SQL Server Compact 4.0 from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx
and I have installed. Once installed If I go to create a data connection as above described it does not appears SQL Server Compact 4.0 from Visual Studio. I would like to use an embedded SQL Server Compact in my project but I am completely lost.

Conclusion: my goal is to use SQL Server Compact edition as embedded in my asp.net mvc 4 web application and put this `.sdf` file in my `\App_Data` folder and make it works with the correct string connection in `web.config`.

Comment: `|DataDirectory|\App_Data` yields `App_Data\App_Data`, if I am not incorrect.  Try `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabaseSQLCe.sdf`.  You can test this by dumping `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString()` on your webpage.

Comment: You are right this was one error on the first approach.The second error in the first approach, regarding the message error, i googled and i find that sql server compact was not made to be used on ASP.NET,because of its several restrictions relating "normal" SQL Server editions and to avoid this message, I should put within Application_Start method in global.asax.cs the following line:AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true), then the error disappears and application goes ok, tables are creaded in database file, etc.

Comment: NOw I would like to know to solve 2 approach using sql server compact 4.0. I have installed it but when trying to create a new data connection from server explorer, the option SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not appear in visual studio, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|DataDirectory|\App_Data` yields **App_Data\App_Data**, if I am not incorrect. Try Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabaseSQLCe.sdf.

You can test this by dumping `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString()` on your webpage.

You should grab the toolkit for visual studio when dealing with Sql Server Compact.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1

Comment: I have installed the sql server compact toolbox from the link you provided, using extension packages in visual studio but when creating dataconnection, sql server compact 4.0 does not appear, only 3.5. I have visual studio 2010 ultimate sp1, and net framework till 4.0.Any ideas? maybe it is not supported in asp.net mvc 4 web applications?

Comment: I have solved: you cannot add a data connection to sql server compact 4.0 from the server explorer and by right click on the data connections node. Instead you need to click on SQL Server Compact Toolbox button at the top of server explorer where appear some buttons. Then a window appears (SQL Server compact toolbox) and right click on SQL Server compact data connections node and in the menu select option Add SQL Server compact 4.0 connection, also you can choose from there 3.5. At first it is a bit confusing until one locates the sql server compact toolbox. Many thanks.